# Intellij IDEA JCEF: Cannot find startup() method in JBR IDE

Tags: java, kotlin, intellij-idea, chromium-embedded

I'm trying to add a WebView (JCEF) as part of a plugin project I'm making for Intellij IDEA. I'm having quite a few issues with it, but I will probably solve most of them. This one I've been working on for hours and still haven't found a fix, so I'm hoping someone here will have some idea.

I have added this to my gradle .kts build file (I think this is the latest JBR IDE version):

```
runIde {
    setJbrVersion("jbr_jcef-11_0_9_1b1244.2")
}
```

The IDE launches fine, but when I click the button that should open the WebView, I get the following error:

`ERROR - .wm.impl.ToolWindowManagerImpl - Cannot init toolwindow com.example.project.toolWindows.JavaLearnHomeToolWindow@3f9c460e  java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: 'boolean org.cef.CefApp.startup()'`

(The tool window is completely empty)

When I manually install the plugin via. the settings on my main IDE (2020.3.1), the browser opens fine. So, I'm presuming that the JBR version does not have the correct version of JCEF. I cannot find how to fix this issue. Here is the code for my window, if needed (please note that I have tried with and without my custom scheme handler (which doesn't work either)):

```
class JavaLearnHomeToolWindowPanel() : SimpleToolWindowPanel(true, false) {

    val browser: JBCefBrowser = JBCefBrowser()
    val browserComponent = browser.component

    init {
        registerAppSchemeHandler()
        browser.loadURL("http://javalearn/index.html")
        browser.openDevtools()
    }

    private fun registerAppSchemeHandler() {
        CefApp.getInstance().registerSchemeHandlerFactory("http", "javalearn", CustomSchemeHandlerFactory())
    }

}
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What runtime version is displayed in the About dialog for the debug IDE version you start from inside IntelliJ IDEA? Is it the same version as used for the main IntelliJ IDEA? You can override JRE in the run/debug configuration.

Comment: CrazyCoder, I have checked this - it is not (and has never been) the same as the installed JDK version of IDEA. As in my post, I have modified the run config to launch the version `jbr_jcef-11_0_9_1b1244.2`, which I think is the latest version according to https://jetbrains.bintray.com/intellij-jbr/ - so I don't know what to do.

Comment: Try using jbr directory from your main IntelliJ IDEA installation as the run configuration JRE.

Comment: I cannot find a `jbr` directory in my IDEA installation.

Comment: What OS do you use and how did you install IntelliJ IDEA?

Comment: I am running Windows 10, and I installed it through the JetBrains Toolbox (currently running version 2020.3.1 of IDEA). Edit: I have looked for `jbr` in the `AppData/Local/JetBrains` and `AppData/Roaming/JetBrains` directories, but can't find anything.

Comment: Toolbox installed IntelliJ IDEA has `jbr` subdirectory, mine is here: `c:\Users\serge\AppData\Local\JetBrains\Toolbox\apps\IDEA-U\ch-0\203.6682.168\jbr`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/226953/discussion-between-sulphate-and-crazycoder).